# Speed up (yet keep file size low) conversion of multiple PNGs to PDF?

Tags: performance, pdf, imagemagick, compression, graphicsmagick

I have 9k PDFs of scanned text I need to clean up/run OCR on. The pages of each PDF are images saved as `.ccitt` which I extract and convert to `.png` using this [Poppler](https://poppler.freedesktop.org/) (for Windows7) command:

```
pdfimages.exe -png file_in.pdf output/images/path
```

After cleaning up the `.png` images I recombine them into a `pdf` using [this ImageMagick command](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=5744):

```
magick.exe convert -compress Group4 -type bilevel -monochrome input/images/path file_out.pdf
```

The resulting `file_out.pdf` is actually smaller than `file_in.pdf` but it takes up to 25 seconds to Group4 compress just 18 images (ranging in size from 58kb to 140kb). **It would take 65 hours to convert all images into 9k+ pdfs this way :'(**

The same thing via [GraphicsMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/index.html):

```
gm convert -compress Group4 -type bilevel -monochrome input/images/path file_out.pdf
```

inflates `file_out.pdf` to **over 40x the size of `file_in.pdf`**.

What am I missing? I thought GraphicsMagick was supposed to be leaner/meaner than ImageMagick.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't simply use all your CPU cores under Windows without installing `mingw` and **GNU Parallel** so in general, all but one of them will sit idle. Consider splitting your list of PDFs into say 4, equal sublists, and running 4 Command Prompts at a time processing a list each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ImageMagick is not a good processor for vector images such as PDF. It will rasterize your PDF and save each dot as an element of the pdf. That may be why it takes so long. The PDF is now a raster image (much larger than the original vector image) in vector shell.

If your input PDF is already black/white, then you only need the compress group 4.

Starting with a 25 KB PDF

If I just convert it.

```
time magick ImageOnly.pdf result1.pdf

real    0m0.276s
user    0m0.563s
sys 0m0.038s

time magick ImageOnly.pdf -compress Group4 result2.pdf

real    0m0.275s
user    0m0.562s
sys 0m0.036s
```

So it is not the group 4 compression that is slowing it dow.

However, the quality will not be terrific. So one should add -density 300 before reading the PDF. But that will slow it down.

```
time magick -density 300 ImageOnly.pdf -compress Group4 result3.pdf

real    0m2.026s
user    0m2.863s
sys 0m0.182s
```

Comment: This sped things up nicely. It's definitely still slow... but removing the extraneous `convert` statement helped a lot. Grazie!